# how to add azure blob storage endpoint to Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-traffic-manager

I'm trying to add the azure blob storage endpoint to traffic manager and its showing degraded.
Could you please provide the steps to add the azure blob storage endpoint in Traffic Manager.